# Using different list icons inside nested UL with fontawesome

Tags: html, css, html-lists, font-awesome

I want to use the double chevron in fontawesome for the top list, and then on the 2nd level i want to use the ordinary bullet points which html provide.

Here is my code;

```
<div class="list">
            <h4>SOLUTIONS</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>Communications Strategy</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Forecasting and benchmarking</li>
                    <li>Editorial charter</li>
                </ul>
                <li>Integrated Editorial Piloting</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Project management support</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.list li {
padding: 0 0 2px 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
color:white;
font-size:0.6875em;
}

.list li:before {
content: '\f101';
font-family:'FontAwesome';
float: left;
padding-left: 1em;
margin-right: 0.2em;
color: #e31b5a;  }
```

Currently it changes all list items to the same fontawesome icon, and i can't find a way to make it look more like this;

http://imageshack.com/a/img921/9828/d4tbEx.png

here is a fiddle;

https://jsfiddle.net/1v3e3c3g/

Any help will be much appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you don't assign class name to sub lists?

Comment: when i use

    .list li.bullet {
    list-style: circle;
    }

it adds the circle but keeps the fontawesome icon in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/1v3e3c3g/1/

```
.list li {
  padding: 0 0 2px 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.6875em;
}
.list > ul {margin-left: 1em;}
.list > ul > li {list-style: none;}
.list > ul > li:before {
  content: '\f101';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  color: #e31b5a;
}
.list > ul > ul {
  margin-left: 2em;
  list-style: initial;
 }
```

I split up your code, and made it more semantic and logic (e.g. margins on the ul, not li).

Answer (score 0):

Add class to those li elements in which you want to add double chevron and then write css for it

```
 <div class="list">
        <h4>SOLUTIONS</h4>
        <ul>
            <li  class="style">Communications Strategy</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Forecasting and benchmarking</li>
                <li>Editorial charter</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="style">Integrated Editorial Piloting</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Project management support</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is the css

```
           .list li.style {
        padding: 0 0 2px 0;
       margin: 0;
       list-style: none;
        color:white;
       font-size:0.6875em;
        }
         .list li {
        padding: 0 0 2px 0;
       margin: 0;
        color:white;
       font-size:0.6875em;
        }

      .list li:before {
       content: '\f101';
         font-family:'FontAwesome';
      float: left;
    padding-left: 1em;
     margin-right: 0.2em;
     color: #e31b5a;  }
```

If it helps you,please mark my answer

Comment: *style* would be the worst class name ever.

Comment: @ALEX should try...i havent but i think  it should work in the desired way

Comment: Are you serious? Your code doesn't work.. Please first try it and share it.

Comment: thanks! it helped point me in the right direction, i was stuck putting classes in the lower levels before

Comment: Sorry for inexact answer..I was in hurry  .You are most welcome